# Why does the POODR book suggest "wrapping the defaults in methods"?

Tags: ruby, oop

In POODR 2nd edition, page 125, Sandy Metz writes

> There are two new messages, default_chain and default_tire_size, sent
> on lines 6 and 7 below. ... Wrapping the defaults in methods is good
> practice in general

The code she's referring to is below. Note how the default value for `chain` and `tire_size` is set.

```
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :chain, :tire_size

  def initialize(**opts)
   @size = opts[:size]
   @chain = opts[:chain] || default_chain
   @tire_size = opts[:tire_size] || default_tire_size
 end

  def default_chain # <- common default
   "11-speed"
  end

  def default_tire_size # <- common default
    "2.1"
  end
end
```

Why is this approach better than the familiar method of simply setting the default value inside `initialize()`, i.e.

```
def initialize(chain: "11-speed", tire_size:"2.1", **opts):
```

This book is about OOP design, so I'm guessing the answer has something to do with good OOP practice but I'm not sure what.

Comment: JFYI, your proposal converts two agruments from keyword to positional. did you mean `def initialize(chain: "11-speed", tire_size: "2.1", **opts)`. That trailing colon suggests that you were thinking in python. In ruby, this syntax behaves differently.

Comment: It's for inheritance. From the book: _"While wrapping the defaults in methods is good practice in general, these new message sends serve a dual purpose. `Bicycle`’s main goal in sending these messages is to give subclasses an opportunity to contribute specializations by overriding them."_ It then gives two examples `RoadBike` and `MountainBike` which provide other defaults.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev, I'm indeed a Python user reading the POODR book :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods are easier to work with. You can stub them in tests or change the implementation (load values from a config file or something like that), all without touching code that uses them.

But the bigger difference between your code and what Sandi suggests is the handling of falsy values.

In your code, it's possible to pass nils explicitly instead of the default value.

```
Bicycle.new(chain: nil, tire_size: "2.1", ...)
```

It might not be a hardcoded nil in your code, but come from somewhere else. Regardless, `Bicycle` will accept it and then maybe crash at runtime when you try to use the value.

Whereas code from the book does not accept nil values, no matter if it's a default nil or explicitly sent. If `chain` is falsy, `"11-speed"` will be used.

Comment: A bit of a dumb question, but how common is this technique? If I google "set default value for attribution", the top Google results all point to setting it in the initializer's signature.

Comment: @Heisenberg: I can't speak for others, but in my code I use argument default values more. But this pattern is common enough to be instantly recognizable. I'd say I do them in 70/30 proportion.

Answer (score 3):

Using a method modularizes the code so that subclasses can override the behavior without overriding the initializer:

```
class MountainBike < Bicycle
  def default_tire_size 
    '18'
  end
end
```

If you used positional arguments `initialize(chain="11-speed", tire_size="2.1", **opts)` this actually is a major downgrade as you now have to remember the order of the arguments. Positional arguments should only be used when there is an obvious order to the arguments.

You can actually set the defaults for both positional and keyword arguments in the arguments list from a method like this:

```
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :chain, :tire_size

  def initialize(tire_size: default_tire_size, chain: default_tire_size, **opts)
    
  end

  # ...
end
```

However its not done very often since it tends to make the method signature very cluttered.

Comment: Good call out about overriding.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev, I hadn't really considered the point about allowing nil values. I guess that a hard one to solve unless you're using defaults in the method signature.

Comment: Funny thing about using non-literals as default values for arguments: You can even use other arguments. :) `def create_article(title: default_title, slug: title.parameterize)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev mind blown ;). I guess you can handle nils with `@size = opts.has_key?(:size) ? opts[:size] : default_size`.

Comment: ah, if you want nils, then yes, `key?` is a good one to use.

Comment: You say potato :). They are both aliases of `include?`

Comment: Indeed, the book suggests one of the reasons is to "avoid overriding the initializer in the subclass". But why is overriding so bad? Reading code in the wild, it doesn't seem uncommon for the subclass initializer to first call `super`, then overrides `tire_size` with its specialized value. This still seems true to the spirit of "subclass specializes the parent class" to me.

Comment: Overriding the initializer isn't always bad. But it requires a degree of knowledge of the implementation of the parent class and calling `super` and overriding the value afterwards might not actually do what you want. Consider for example if super sets `@metric_tiresize = to_metric(@tire_size)`. A set of documented methods instead creates a API for inherting classes to use.